# Stuck on fastboot with broken power button

Tags: fastboot, power-on, oneplus-3

Phone isn't recognized by a USB cable even after installing the official drivers. So `fastboot reboot` wouldn't work. Power button is broken, so the phone is stuck on the fastboot screen. What can I do to reboot the phone to normal??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you always end up in fastboot mode the power is not the only one broken. Seems like your volume buttons are also broken so that the phone recognizes them as permanently pressed (or at least the volume down button).

Answer (score 0):

You can try running "fastboot continue" while connected to a PC.